# Spring MVC LightAdmin configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, lightadmin

I'm trying to setup LightAdmin page for my web application, I'm following https://github.com/la-team/light-admin. After following this step a see this error:

```
 14:36:55.705 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@77bc4d5: defining beans [dataSource,userJDBCTemplate,teamJDBCTemplate,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
 14:36:55.708 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}
 ....
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>light:administration:base-url</param-name>
    <param-value>/admin</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>light:administration:security</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>light:administration:base-package</param-name>
    <param-value>com.project.config</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.wirecardproject</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<name>Wirecard project</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LightAdmin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lightadmin</groupId>
        <artifactId>lightadmin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and root_context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

```
<!-- Definition for userJDBCTemplate bean -->
<bean id="userJDBCTemplate" class="users.UserJDBCTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Definition for scriptJDBCTemplate bean -->
<bean id="teamJDBCTemplate" class="teams.TeamJDBCTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Could you help me? I'm trying to have admin page to create/update/delete/show Users and Teams. Or is there a better way how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The message is referring to an absence of `persistence.xml` file. This file is usually holding references of the entities you defined for Hibernate/JPA.

Based on the files you submitted I was not completely able to reproduce your issue, do you have a way to share your project on GitHub ? Can you provide a bit extra insights about how you're deploying it ?

Comment: I'm just starting, so I'm deploying it locally using my Spring Tool Suite IDE and Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition. Here is my project on GitHub, if you'd know a problem, it would be very helpful for me. https://github.com/LenkaDzurjakova/project.git

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at your project. I don't see where you are using jpa, it seems you are using jdbctemplate for data access.

Why don't you remove these lines from your config and see if that gets you farther.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

If you configure jpa related beans you are telling Spring-Boot not to auto-configure, and then you are responsible for replacing the "magic" that the framework does for you.

Spring boot should provide reasonable default configurations. You can add specific configuration later when-and-if you start using JPA(entities, repositories, etc)  to access your data.

In your HomeController could you try this:

```
@Autowired
private UserJDBCTemplate userJDBCTemplate;

@Autowired
private TeamJDBCTemplate teamJDBCTemplate;
```

instead of this:

```
ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("root-context.xml");

    UserJDBCTemplate ubd =(UserJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("userJDBCTemplate");
    TeamJDBCTemplate tbd =(TeamJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("teamJDBCTemplate");
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but now I'm getting

        java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener or DispatcherServlet registered?
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:252)
 org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)